# Can't find my extension option under administer>System settings

Tags: extension, civirules, modules

I installed CiViCRM on WordPress and imported a Drupal CiViCRM database into it. everything seemed to work well. Just that I'm getting few errors such as 
**Unknown extension: org.civicoop.civirules.**
**Error loading module file (). Please restore the file or disable the module**

I want to fix those errors. I wanted to access the extension option under administer>System settings but can't find the option to add or remove extensions. Hope you could help me fix this issue.
I am using  CiviCRM 4.7.27 on WordPress

Thank you

Comment: [![I'm using WordPress. Please, Have a look at my Interface. The extension option isn't part of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIxA2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIxA2.png) **I'm using WordPress. Please, Have a look at my Interface. The extension option isn't part of the menu**

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much. I saw the the extension table in the database and I downloaded and placed the extension in the extension folder but still the same error. The issue is that I don't have access to the Extension option under Administer to reinstall or install any extension

Comment: <whatever it needs in worpress>/civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1 Please the link didn't work. can you provide a more detailed link?

Answer (score 2):

The extensions need code files that are not in your database, but your imported database will have a table called civicrm_extension with a list of the installed extensions.

So it will expect every extension in that table to be present (code files) in the correct spot. Obviously that is not the case. You need to either re-install these extensions OR also copy the extension directory from your source installation. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

From the information you've given, it sounds like you should simply need to re-install the Civirules extension from scratch.

[image: Administer > System Settings > Extensions]

From the extensions page, select Add New to find the list of available but not yet downloaded extensions, you can sort them alphabetically by clicking "Extension Name (Key)". Then find Civirules and click Download.

[image]

Civirules should now be in your downloaded Extensions, and if not already enabled should give you an option to Install.